# How do I modify the data I upload directly from the database into pbi

Tags: database, powerbi, connection, live

I'd like to be able to have data upload itself directly from the database into power bi.In theory I can do that by getting the data from a connector but it is very messy.
Can I somehow modify it but still be able to have it directly refresh itself in my report ?

Answer (score 0):

To modify the data coming from the database into your Power BI model, use a [Power Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-query-overview) to apply transformations to the source data.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback but what I failed to mention Is that I can only load 2 tables from my database but I need information from more